Find $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{ x^3 }{e^x - 1}\,dx$ using Fourier series.
Can someone help me solve this integral using Fourier series?
I already know the other methods and the answer, but I’d like someone to explain it using Fourier series.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please don't pay attention to that bot, but format your formulas and include your question in the body of your post, as well as your attempts to solve it.

Fourier techniques are not typically used on problems involving the half-line.

$\displaystyle\Gamma\left(4\right)\zeta\left(4\right) = {\pi^{4} \over 15}$.

@whpowell96 I suspect the question is really about the exponential series $$\frac{1}{e^x-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty } e^{-n x}.$$
